# DHTML modal window, close on background click

Tags: javascript, popup, dhtml

I am using the dhtml window widget script found here:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/dhtmlwindow/index.htm

I would like for the user to be able to close the dhtml popup window when clicking the background. Currently it only works when clicking the close button. How do I add that to this script?

Comment: Add a div element that stretched the whole view-port width and hight and is positioned behind the window, then add an onclick listener and call the method that the close buttons calls. If you run into trouble, post your code...

Comment: Sorry I'm a novice at this. I posted the link to the code. I'm using window 3 option. JS file is there to view.

Comment: How do I use these functions


t.hide=function(){dhtmlwindow.hide(this)} //public function for hiding dhtml window
 t.close=function(){dhtmlwindow.close(this)} //public function for closing dhtml window (also empties DHTML window content)

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT for "dhtmlmodal" as the subject says.  This is for "dhtmlwindow".  There IS a difference as "dhtmlmodal" does not even seem to have a .close() event, only a .hide()

Answer (score 0):

That widget is quite old now (over 6 years) and there are no doubt numerous newer, better alternatives, but that's besides the point.

The documentation on the page you linked to details how to create the popup, and then how to access functions that act on the pop up. Copied below for reference:

```
Create links that manipulate an opened window in various ways when clicked on

<script type="text/javascript">
// this function invocation generates the popup with your specific parameters
// the variable name you assign (googlewin) is used to interact with the popup later
var googlewin=dhtmlwindow.open("googlebox", "iframe", "http://google.com", "Google Web site", "width=700px,height=450px,resize=1,scrolling=1,center=1", "recal")
</script>

<!-- this is an example link that will call the close method on the googlewin object
this is the bit you need to apply to whatever it is that you want the visitor to be able to click on to close the popup -->
<a href="#" onClick="googlewin.close(); return false">Close Window</a>
```

Bear in mind that the widget you are using creates a popup window, not a true modal. If you were to use a modal (lightbox) you would have built in close functionality whenever the visitor clicked anywhere outside of the main modal content area.

Comment: Yes, I know how to create it. I'm asking if it is possible to add the ability to close this popup window when clicked outside of it like lightbox image windows. Currently it only works on a link in the popup window.

Comment: And its not a popup window, its modal in the browser window.